# Simplifying integrals with greatest integer in arguments

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

Suppose $ \int_{0}^{1}\sin( (x-[x]) \pi) dx$

This inside argument of this $\sin(x)$ spans $0$ to $\pi$, therefore I thought this integral would be $\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(x) dx$

But it is infact, $ \int_{0}^{1} \sin(x \pi)dx$

Now I understand we can proof this fact by simplifying accounting the fact that $[x]$ is $0$ on our domain. However suppose, I did not have such a 'nice' bounds, then how would I identify if the function was composition or not? As in, how would I know that I had to divide by $\pi$ in the first one.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{a}^{b}sin( (x-[x]) \pi) dx$$
We can always write $x-[x]$ as {$x$}.
Also, as it is periodic with period $1$,
We can write it as,
$$\int_{a}^{b}sin( (x-[x]) \pi) dx=\int_{a}^{b}sin(\{x\} \pi) dx=(b-a)\int_{0}^{1}sin( x\pi) dx$$
$$\text{substitute } \pi x\rightarrow t \Rightarrow dx\rightarrow \frac {dt}{\pi}$$
Thus we get,$$\frac{(b-a)}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}sin( x) dx$$

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_{0}^{1} \sin (\{x\}\pi)  dx,$$
where $\{x\}$ is fractional part of $x$ and for $x \in (0,1)$, $\{x\}=x$
Si $$I=\int_{0}^{1} \sin \pi x ~dx=-]\cos \pi x]_{0}^{1}=\frac{2}{\pi}$$